Xdebug hangs, when xdebug.mode=debug
I have Php 8.2.12, and Xdebug 8.2.12 (php_xdebug-3.3.2-8.2-vs16-x86_64.dll)
The exact config:
extension=php_xdebug-3.3.2-8.2-vs16-x86_64.dll
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
xdebug.mode=coverage
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9001
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.start_with_request=1
xdebug.dump_globals=1
xdebug.dump=COOKIE,FILES,GET,POST,REQUEST,SERVER,SESSION
xdebug.dump.SERVER=REMOTE_ADDR,REQUEST_METHOD,REQUEST_URI
xdebug.show_local_vars=1
xdebug.collect_return=1
xdebug.trace_options=0
xdebug.trace_format=0
xdebug.trace_output_dir=""
xdebug.trace_output_name="trace.%t"
xdebug.profiler_append=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=""
xdebug.profiler_output_name="cachegrind.out.%s.%t"
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.log="c:\xampp\php\xdebug.log"

with this config xdebug and browser works, phpinfo() tells xdebug is allright. But I want to:
xdebug.mode=debug

and this causes the browser hangs. What to do?

To resolve the issue of Xdebug hanging when set to "debug" mode, ensure you have a proper IDE or debugger client configured to connect to the specified client host and port. Xdebug in debug mode waits for a connection with a debugging client (like an IDE). If no client connects, Xdebug waits indefinitely, causing the browser to hang. To fix this, either connect a debugging client to the specified host and port or switch Xdebug to a non-debugging mode, like "develop" or "coverage," until you are ready to debug

Xdebug will not wait indefinitely. There's a default timeout of 200 ms, which you can tweak to your liking: xdebug.connect_timeout_ms

cool, that seems to work. Now I cant debug, since it wont stop on breakpoints

This answer is incorrect. Xdebug does not wait indefinitely as Álvaro says. Most likely it just started a debugging connection and is waiting for the IDE to send commands or do otherwise things. Create a log (you already do that), and set xdebug.log_level=11. It should then tell exactly what is going on.
